# View the stack when debugging Java website in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp

I have just started to work on a large (built by previous developers) Java EE web application. It uses Spring and JSP pages. The way that things are implemented are not always consistent, basically its a big fat legacy system.

My problem is that I'm having a very difficult time finding what classes are being called to get data and build the model view for each page. (The front controller is not straight forward...)

**Is there any way to trace exactly what files are used when a page is displayed in browser?**

I think viewing the stack trace is what I need but I cant find it in Eclipse. This could be an IDE issue.

FYI: The project is in Java, using (mostly) the Spring Framework, JSP pages, XML to format the content of the JSP pages, Tomcat Server in Eclipse.

Comment: When you go to the debug perspective, there is a debug view showing the current stack trace of the methods being executed. Maybe it was closed by you or somewhere else in the team.

Comment: I think no such ready tools available. To add more to above comment, if Spring MVC is used, you could start by adding debug break points to the controller classes and invoke appropriate pages to view that stacktrace. You could also try to reverse engineer existing code to UML models which may be help.